# Python input in while loop

Tags: python, bots, irc

I'm making an IRC bot in python,
now I want to have some console commands.

The main function is in a while loop, so I can't put `input_raw()`. Does anyone know how to get user input while not interrupt the loop.

thanks!

Comment: Use threads. One for the IRC handling, one for the input.

Comment: i made 2 threads, 1 with the IRC base and one with a = raw_input just to test... but i can't do any input

Comment: Update your question with your code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved, used Threading,
source: [FaceBot source](https://github.com/FaceHunter/FaceBot)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use non-blocking sockets with `select`. Something like:

```
from sys import stdin
from select import select

while True:
    print "Enter command> ",
    # Add on_write sockets as necessary
    on_read, _, _ = select([stdin], [], [], 5)
    if on_read:
        command = stdin.readline()
        print "Now I can process you command..."
    else:
        print "No command, we can do here something else..."
```

Comment: This would only work if the IRC bot function were something that could be "pumped" every loop. If its a service that goes into its own blocking loop then threads would still be needed.

Comment: @jdi If IRC bot function is something that make heavy calculations or something like thing (utilize too much CPU), threads will not help much. But usually, IRC bot is something that should perform read/write operations.

Comment: Yea I wasn't really specifying that the OP **should** use thread over process. I was just speaking about the fact that the OP might have to completely restructure the "irc bot" function into something that can process pending operations and exit, so that it would work in your suggestion.

Comment: hmm well, this is a little too complicated for me... when i've learned more of python i'll re-look into the problem